# How to direct download large file from Google drive without Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses message

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsurl

I'm trying to play a music file in my Google drive but it's about 300mb so Google won't let me directly download it using this link.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12cpUAP0wy8jyMD4-rjKJ23bicCJ29Cs-
```

There is a "google drive can't scan this file message" and download anyway button. I then inspected download anyway button using Chrome and saw this link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=9iBg&id=12cpUAP0wy8jyMD4-rjKJ23bicCJ29Cs-
```

so I tried it to play audio using below func and it worked

```
audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

However, the url from download anyway button keeps changing from confirm=9iBg to confirm=???? which makes it impossible to play the audio again unless I have to go to my code and change that id manually. Is there a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using their REST API interface ? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it cannot be done without the confirmation window, most likely token `&confirm=9iBg&id=12cpUAP0wy8jyMD4-rjKJ23bicCJ29Cs-` has an expiration date, and is renewed only by the confirmation window.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution when solving the same problem today. I am using shell to automatic download a file from google drive. The key is to set a cookie and retrieve the confirm code dynamically from the first download attempt result html page content:

```
printf "${WHITE}Downloading ${fileNames[$i]}${NC}\n"
curl -L -c mycookie -o temp "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileLinks[$i]}"
filesize=$(wc -c temp | awk '{print $1}')
if [ $filesize -gt 10000 ]; then
  printf "Finish downloading\n"
  mv temp "${fileNames[$i]}.tar.gz"
else
  content=$(cat temp)
  for (( j=0; j<$filesize-10; j++)); do
    if [ "${content:$j:8}" == "confirm=" ]; then
      for (( k=0; k<10; k++)); do
        if [ "${content:$j+8+$k:1}" == "&" ]; then
          token=${content:$j+8:$k}
        fi
      done
    fi
  done
  printf "Confirm downloading with token ${token}\n"
  curl -L -b mycookie -o "${fileNames[$i]}.tar.gz" "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=${token}&id=${fileLinks[$i]}"
  rm mycookie
  rm temp
fi
```